# What is supposed to be an iteration technique?

Tags: hash, cryptography, theory, sha

I was asked at the coding theory course to implement a compression hash function and an **iteration technique** of my choice.

What is supposed to mean "**an iteration technique**" ?

I choosed SHA-1 for the hash func.

P.S. Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, that's why I'm asking such an ambiguous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably refers to the creation of an iterative hash function using a compression hash function as mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) and [here](http://www.ics.mq.edu.au/~kmatus/HashFunctions-NTU2007.pdf).